# After dismissing a TextField in a static UITableView, cells are not loaded when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This is my first time asking a question, so if I'm making any faux pas, please let me know.

I am working on an app for iOS 11. I have a storyboard with a static UITableView. A few cells have a UITextField, but most only have a UILabel. All of the UILabel.text values are set in the Storyboard.

There are more cells than fit on an iPhone screen, and the cells that initially aren't visible only have a UILabel. When the table view first loads, I can scroll to the bottom of the view and those cells appear as expected. (The last section of the table view shows five cells)

However, if I tap a UITextField then dismiss the keyboard, when I scroll down the cells no longer appear. (The last section has only one cell instead of five). If I scroll back to the top and then to the bottom again, the missing cells load properly again.

Because the table is static and created with Storyboard, I do not implement  UITableViewDataSource.

I dismiss the textField as below:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the problem might be, or where I could start looking to debug this? Because the table is static, there aren't many places in my TableViewController where I can interact with the rows.

Thanks

Comment: Could we look at your cell binding code where you dequeue the cell and assign the correct values to the cell? and also the delegate methods for number of rows in section and number of sections. And when you say the cells do not appear, do you mean that there are no more cells past that or cells appear but seem to have nothing?

Comment: @Khanal, I updated my question to address your questions. Let me know if you still need clarification.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue and I am unable too. Created a storyboard with a tableviewcontroller, added two sections and a bunch of cells with UITextField and UILabel. Did not implement datasource. Thought I would let you know.